Why is mean harmonicity of a pure noise a valid value as measured in Praat?
In Praat, I created a pure Gaussian noise with randomGauss(0,0.2). In my opinion, since no f0 information can be traced from the signal, the harmonicity of the sound will be an invalid value, such as infinity, undefined, or some very small value such as -200 dB, but it turns out to be a valid value: -7.43 dB.
You can reproduce this in Praat by:

New -> Sound -> Create Sound from formula with formula randomGauss(0,0.2).
With the sound object created, To Harmonicity (cc) with all arguments default.
With the harmonicity object, Query -> Get mean, set time range to all.

